Ignore tag in ASG resource
I'm trying to prevent a change to a tag value from causing a change in terraform plan.
tag {
    key     = "Name"
    value   = "${var.stage}-${var.name}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  tag {
    key     = "commit_location"
    value   = data.aws_ssm_parameter.commit_location.value
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tag["commit-location"]
    ]
  }

terraform plan results in an error:
│   on ../modules/ec2/asg.tf line 61, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg":
│   61:       tag["commit_location"]
│
│ Block type "tag" is represented by a set of objects, and set elements do not have addressable keys. To find elements matching specific criteria, use a "for" expression with an "if" clause.

I was expecting that a change to this tag (i.e. a change to the value of data.aws_ssm_parameter.commit_location.value) to not cause a change for this resource in terrazform plan.
I noted that there seems to have been a change in behavior of the tag/tags block in AWS provider v5 which might be causeing this issue.  I've read several bug reports but they don't seem to have an answer after more than 12 months.
More Info:
I tried the solution below
# tag {
  #   key     = "Name"
  #   value   = "${var.stage}-${var.name}"
  #   propagate_at_launch = true
  # }

  # tag {
  #   key     = "commit_location"
  #   value   = data.aws_ssm_parameter.commit_location.value
  #   propagate_at_launch = true
  # }

  # lifecycle {
  #   ignore_changes = [
  #     tag
  #   ]
  # }

  # Define tags as a map
  dynamic "tag" {
    for_each = {
      Name            = "${var.stage}-${var.name}"
      commit_location = data.aws_ssm_parameter.commit_location.value
    }
    content {
      key                 = tag.key
      value               = tag.value
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    # Use the 'for_each' approach to manage tags dynamically
    ignore_changes = [
      tags[*].value if tag.key == "commit_location"
    ]
  }

but it resulted in a different error
Error: Invalid expression
│
│   on ../modules/ec2/asg.tf line 86, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg":
│   86:       tags[*].value if tag.key == "commit_location"
│
│ A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template
│ expressions, etc are allowed here. (tags[*].value is underlined)
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing item separator
│
│   on ../modules/ec2/asg.tf line 86, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg":
│   85:     ignore_changes = [
│   86:       tags[*].value if tag.key == "commit_location"
│
│ Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next item. ("if" is underlined)

I do think this solution is along the lines of what the devs intended the solution to be though.  It just isn't quite working for me yet.  Hopefully someone can make heads or tails of that error message.  thanks.

You’re right as I believe in AWS provider v5, the tag block is treated as a set of objects, which means you can't reference individual tags using keys like tag["commit_location"]. To fix this, you need to adjust how you handle tags in Terraform.
You can't directly reference a specific tag in the ignore_changes block like tag["commit_location"] because sets don't have addressable keys just as the error suggests. Here's how I would address this issue:
If you're okay with ignoring changes to all tags for this resource, you can use the following:
lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = [tags]
}

This will prevent any changes to the tags from triggering a change in the Terraform plan.
OR
If you only want to ignore changes to a specific tag (e.g., commit_location), you can use a more dynamic approach. Since tags are now a set, you can apply a for_each loop to define tags.
For example:
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  # Define tags as a map
  dynamic "tag" {
    for_each = {
      Name            = "${var.stage}-${var.name}"
      commit_location = data.aws_ssm_parameter.commit_location.value
    }
    content {
      key                 = tag.key
      value               = tag.value
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    # Use the 'for_each' approach to manage tags dynamically
    ignore_changes = [
      tags[*].value if tag.key == "commit_location"
    ]
  }
}

Here, the for_each block dynamically generates the tags, and ignore_changes is applied to ignore changes to the specific commit_location tag using the for_each loop.
Either option ‘should’ prevent unwanted changes to tag values from triggering a change in the Terraform plan.

I'm not looking to ignore changes to all tags, just the one.  I tried your solution but it resulted in a different error message, although I think this is along the lines of what the devs intended the solution to be. (sorry, don't know how to answer with code snippets)
